# How can I get just the file name without absolute path, in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I am trying to print the file names that are including the extension of (.gz) in directory. currently i have the below shell script which is printing the absolute path. I want to print only the file name.

can someone advise on this. I have tried different ways.

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceFolder=/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/*.gz

sleepTimeinMinutes=200

cd $sourceFolder

for f in $sourceFolder do
   echo " printing the file name $f" done
```

the current output is :

```
printing the file name
/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/app-json.log copy 10.gz 
printing the file name
/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/app-json.log copy 11.gz 
printing the file name
/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/app-json.log copy 12.gz 
printing the file name
/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/app-json.log copy 2.gz  printing
the file name /Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/app-json.log copy
3.gz
```

I want only the file name:

e.g. `app-json.log copy 10.gz`

Comment: You don't need to `cd` to the folder since you've already declared a full path. Incidentally, it's better to use `cd "$folder" || exit`, and in the loop quote the variable:`"$sourceFolder".` and `sourceFolder="/Users/rojadhanavath/Desktop/app/logs/*.gz"` and `cd "$sourceFolder"`

Comment: It's probable there's an error message from `cd` that you haven't shown us, above the `printing the file name` loop

Answer (score 3):

You can take the basename of `$f`:

```
for f in $sourceFolder; do
    echo " printing the file name $(basename $f)"
done
```

or, since you already used `cd $sourceFolder`, this will work as well:

```
for f in *.gz; do
    echo " printing the file name $f"
done
```

Comment: thank you for the response. i was running this script on a server- the issue was related to specific server and i have update apt package and it worked.

Comment: No problem. You can click the checkmark on an answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate answer is @laktak. But here there's another approach:

```
for f in "$sourceFolder"; do 
  echo " printing the file name ${f##*/}"
done
```

Comment: I think that might want to be `"${f##*/}"`. The wildcard applies to the directory name -- i.e. everything before the last `/`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes! I misplaced the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The file-extension part is easy. There is no such thing. There are some tools that will help you work with this concept (e.g. `basename`), but they don't exist, so just ignore it. For what you need use the tool `dirname`.

e.g.

```
echo " printing the file name $(dirname "$f")"
```